# Pointers and printf

Tags: c, linux, string, pointers

I have following code written in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void fortune(char msg[]){
  printf("Message reads: %s\n", msg);
  printf("msg occupies %ld bytes.\n", sizeof(msg));
}

int main(){
  char quote[]= "Cookies make you fat";
  fortune(quote);   
  printf("The quote string is at %p\n", quote); //ONE
  printf("The quote string is at %p\n", &quote); //TWO
}
```

I know int variables if we want to get address of it we must write:

```
printf("a is located at %p\n", &a);  not   printf("a is located at %p\n", a);
```

But I want to know the difference between the first and the second version (see the lines named ONE and TWO in the snippet)?

Comment: `%p` is `printf` format for pointer value. `&` is used to get the memory address of a variable (i.e. a pointer).

Comment: I know... I want to know wha the diference between these two lines is:  printf("The quote string is at %p\n", quote); 
  printf("The quote string is at %p\n", &quote);

Comment: C or C++? Pick one...

Comment: Besides all, your code provokes undefined behaviour, as `"%p"` is defined to print `void *` only. It shall be `printf("The quote string is at %p\n", (void *) quote); ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The address printed in both ONE and TWO will be the same. **quote** is an array, and at ONE the name is converted to a pointer to its first element, and at TWO **&quote** will have a different data type than **quote**, but it will still be a pointer to the start to the array **quote**.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following:

```
const char *pStr = "Hello";

printf("pStr   = %p\n", pStr);
printf("&pStr  = %p\n", &pStr);
printf("pStr   = %s\n", pStr);
printf("*&pStr = %s\n", *&pStr);
```

On my machine I get the following results:

```
pStr   = 0x100403030
&pStr  = 0x22aac8
pStr   = Hello
*&pStr = Hello
```

What this means is the following:

1. `pStr` is the address of the first character in the string, `'H'` in this example.
2. `&pStr` is the address of the pointer that holds the address of the first character in the string.

Visualize it like this:

```
Identifier   pStr
Value      | 2000 | ... | 'H'  || 'e'  || 'l'  || 'l'  || 'o'  || '\0' |
Address      1000         2000    2001    2002    2003    2004    2005
```

In the above example, `pStr` has a value of `2000`, which is the address of the first character of the string, `"Hello"`.  `&pStr` is the address of the pointer itself, which is `1000`.

Now, consider the following:

```
const char pStr[] = "Goodbye";

printf("pStr     = %p\n", pStr);
printf("&pStr    = %p\n", &pStr);
printf("&pStr[0] = %p\n", &pStr[0]);
printf("pStr     = %s\n", pStr);
printf("*&pStr   = %s\n", *&pStr);
printf("&pStr[0] = %s\n", &pStr[0]);

return 0;
```

After executing this, I get the following output on my machine:

```
pStr     = 0x22aac0
&pStr    = 0x22aac0
&pStr[0] = 0x22aac0
pStr     = Goodbye
*&pStr   = Goodbye
&pStr[0] = Goodbye
```

As you can see, `pStr`, `&pStr`, and `&pStr[0]` all result in the same address.  This shows you that, though many times an array can be thought of as a pointer to memory, it is fundamentally different.

You can think of `pStr`, `&pStr`, and `&pStr[0]` as all being aliases for the same thing, the address of the first character of the string `"Goodbye"`, `'G'` in this example.

Comment: Why then both address are coming the same?

Comment: This is a nice answer, but not to the question that was asked. Here **pStr** is a pointer and not an array. Arrays are not pointers, and work differently. With your code, you will get different behavior than in the OP's code.

Comment: Agreed with @ThomasPadron-McCarthy. The behavior of your code is different from that of OP.

Comment: @Thomas Padron-McCarthy: Thanks for clarification. Your point solved my doubt.

Comment: @FiddlingBits; If you run OP's code then both of the address would be same. See the answer given by @Thomas.

Comment: @FiddlingBits: I was pointing towards the code posted by MortezaLSC where both addresses will be same.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question.  Updating.

Comment: @alk Should I explicitly cast `pStr` to `void *`, or does that happen implicitly?

Comment: note: when you put "Goodbye man" this is two word///and these are all the same printf("pStr     = %s\n", pStr);
printf("*&pStr   = %s\n", *&pStr);
printf("&pStr[0] = %s\n", &pStr[0]); and print complete string

Comment: Casting is always explicitly and should not be mixed up with "conversion" which could happen "implicitly". It shall be `printf("pSt = %p\n", (void *) pStr);`

Comment: In my code I have sizeof that it shows the sizeof pointer(first character)

Answer (score 2):

In this case there is no difference between the two forms.
Why? Simply because you are printing a memory address using `%p`; being `quote` basically a pointer to the first element (which is `C`), you are *already* passing `printf` a memory address. There is no need to use the `&` operator, even though it can make the syntax clearer.